# Access mdframed node coordinates with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

Is it possible to get a (breakable) frame like this with `mdframed`? Or as a more general question. Can one access the coordinates of the frame that is drawn with TikZ?

[image: desired result]

With a pagebreak in it:
[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]

I build this example with the following code.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\NewEnviron{excursustikz}{%
   \par
   \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
   \noindent
   \begin{tikzpicture}%
      \node (body) [%
         text width=\textwidth-4pt-2ex,
         inner sep=0pt,
      ] {\BODY};
      \draw [
         line width=4pt,
         blue,
         line cap=round,
         rounded corners=2ex,
         ->
      ] ($(body.south west)+(5em,-2ex)$) -| ($(body.west)+(-2ex,0)$) |- %
        ($(body.north)+(-12em,2ex)$) .. controls +(0:10em) and +(190:5em) .. ++(20em,2ex);
      \node [blue,fill=white] at ($(body.north west)+(3.5em,2.36ex)$) {\sffamily\bfseries Excursus};
   \end{tikzpicture}%^
   \par
   \vspace{0.25\baselineskip}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{excursustikz}
   \lipsum[2]
\end{excursustikz}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The node that I imagine to use is `body`, but I’m not sure if `mdframed` uses a node internally. Furthermore one has to care about a page spanning frame. In that case the line at the right should be broken, as if you cut the path in two parts.

Comment: Your solutions seem to produce good results. I was going to suggest using `\tikzmark`, but handing the page crossing boundary is a bit more difficult.

Comment: @PeterGrill: This is the reason why I asked to “hack in” `mdframed` which handles the breaks very well and uses (can use) TikZ to draw the frames

Comment: `mdframed` knows how to break text when **it** encounters a page boundary, but _not_ how to place material on a page **before** the start of an `mdframed`, which is the case you point out where the frame begins on a subsequent page.  If you are only interested in the case where the `mdframed` **begins** on the same page as the text you want to point to, but that the text box can span pages, that is different.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Im not sure sure if I understand you right … I added two images showing the desired frame if it’s. So what I want to do is replace the top line by an arrow with the text and the bottom line should not span the whole line width.

Comment: @Tobi: What you want is perfectly possible. You can use `mdframed` for the computing and the lines can be drawn by the predefined coordinates `O` and `P`. For the settings in `mdframed.sty` I recommend `topline=true,leftline=true,bottomline=true,rightline=false`.

Comment: PS: Do you remember our talk at the DANTE mailing list ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I skimmed the implementation of `mdframed` but overlook the relevant part :-)

Comment: PS: Do you mean the one about feature requests? Sure :-)

Comment: @Tobi: Of course ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** To let `mdframed` know the right dimensions of the frame to calculate the page breaks we must give them as invisible margins (`middleline`) and adjust everything according to these. See the updated code below.

---

Marco’s comment lead me to the relevant parts in the manual. Here is my code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\tikzstyle{excursus arrow}=[%
   line width=4pt,
   draw=blue,
   rounded corners=2ex
]
\tikzstyle{excursus head}=[%
   fill=white,
   font={\bfseries\sffamily},
   text=blue,
   anchor=base,
]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\drawexcursusarrow}{%
   \patchcmd{\mdf@putbox@single}{\mdfcreateextratikz}{
      \path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
      \path let \p1=(Q), \p2=(O) in (\x1,{(\y1-\y2)/2}) coordinate (M);
      \path [excursus arrow, round cap->]
         ($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (M) |- %
         ($(Q)+(6em,0ex)$) .. controls +(0:16em) and +(185:6em) .. %
         ++(23em,2ex);
      \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(4.5em,-2pt)$) {Excursus};
   }{}{}%
   \patchcmd{\mdf@putbox@first}{\mdfcreateextratikz}{
      \path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
      \path [excursus arrow,->]
         (O) |- %
         ($(Q)+(6em,0ex)$) .. controls +(0:16em) and +(185:6em) .. %
         ++(23em,2ex);
      \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(4.5em,-2pt)$) {Excursus};
   }{}{}%
   \patchcmd{\mdf@putbox@second}{\mdfcreateextratikz}{
      \path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
      \path [excursus arrow,round cap-]
         ($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (Q);
   }{}{}%
   \patchcmd{\mdf@putbox@middle}{\mdfcreateextratikz}{
      \path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
      \path [excursus arrow]
         (O) -- (Q);
   }{}{}%
}
\makeatother
\newmdenv[%
   middlelinewidth=24pt,
   middlelinecolor=green,
   rightline=false,
   innertopmargin=0ex,
   innerbottommargin=0ex,
   innerrightmargin=2pt,
   innerleftmargin=0ex,
   leftmargin=-11pt,
   skipabove=12pt,
   skipbelow=-1pt,%=12-24/2-2/2
   settings=\drawexcursusarrow,
]{excursus}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{excursus}
   \lipsum[1]
\end{excursus}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

I used `\pathcmd` to differentiate between the broken and unbroken frames. Furthermore I draw the arrow with `\drawexcursusarrow` and apply this via the `settings` key only to the `{excursus}` environment, so my changes don’t effect the other frames.

---

### Bonus question

is it possible to let `mdframed` ignore the descenders of the last line in the frame? Otherwise the (optical) `innerbottomsep` depends on these.

Comment: Nice one. You can define a command `patchframes` and execute it at the option `settings` ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Did it while you write the comment :-) and I added a bonus question, but maybe I should post this as a new question (?)

Comment: I can't understand the intention of your bonus question.

Comment: I’ll post it as a fresh question an try to make it clear :-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: [Here it is …](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47584/4918)