# Preventing letters with descenders (g, q, y...) from affecting line spacing

Tags: spacing

I'm making layouts for a card game, and characters that have a descender component (like g, q, y...) are messing up the spacing. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
blah
\\[0.2\baselineskip]
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

results in the image being placed higher than

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
glah
\\[0.2\baselineskip]
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

How can I prevent this (without having to place things in different nodes or anything like that)? Right now I'm adding `\vphantom{g}` (or `\strut`) to lines that don't have descenders, but it's not a very elegant solution.

Right now the only time I see this arise is with `\baselineskip` (and it is indeed possible to avoid using those), but I'm doing a bunch of things that need to be independent of the letters used. I'm already using a ttfamily font so they take up the same horizontal space, it'd be really nice if they could also take up the same vertical space.

Comment: Please make your code snippets compilable ...

Comment: Is the image important? Does there have to be an image? Maybe `\rule{2cm}{2cm}` does just fine?

Comment: Use `\strut` at the beginning of those lines (blahblah and glahglah).

Comment: @Johannes_B yeah, using \strut works, but it's not much better than using \vphantom{g}, I still have to put it manually on every offending line. Isn't there a way to do it globally?

Comment: As long as you add `\\[.2\baselineskip]` everywhere by hand, there is no use in looking for a global solution.

Comment: If you give a complete example of the layout you're trying to achieve (not just one line, but something enough for someone to see the big picture), then someone may have a better idea for how to achieve that layout. Generally, something like `\\[0.2\baselineskip]` is a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR True, I can avoid using \baselineskip. Inside tikz pictures it's kind of a hassle though since I have to reset the \parskip... Anyway, pretend its an academic question: is there a way to make all letters take the same vertical space? (I'm using a tt font so they already take the same horizontal space)

Comment: @Alexbib Yes sure, use or create a [virtual] font in which all letters take the same vertical space (e.g. change the font metrics). Or use `\strut` on every line. Or change the values of `\baselineskip`, `\lineskip` and `\lineskiplimit`, to change the behaviour of the interline glue. Or include every letter in a box. Or other solutions; it's really hard to say what's best without knowing the use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the previous depth before adding the vertical space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\fixedvspace}[1]{%
  \par\kern-\prevdepth\vspace{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
\hrule

blah
\fixedvspace{0.2\baselineskip}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}

\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
\hrule

glah
\fixedvspace{0.2\baselineskip}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The `\hrule here is just to anchor the minipage to have the reference point at the very top.

There may be simpler workarounds in your specific setting that seems quite specialized. The trick could be hidden in the syntax you use for laying out the card game.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, this way seems pretty logical!

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't so much the descender in the text as the fact that the height of the image forces `\lineskip` glue spacing.  LaTeX doesn't have that good a way to avoid that but you can do this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\showoutput
\begin{document}

glah


\mbox{}\\
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

so that you get `\baselineskip` spacing between the text and the empty `\mbox` (which therefore adjusts to the depth of the text) and get a fixed `\lineskip` spacing in all cases before the image. If the empty box line is more space than you want use `\\[-\baselineskip]` or whatever instead of `\\` after the `\mbox{}`

Answer (score 2):

Even if David Carlisle's vision is better, you may use something like this (with your actual code), with the `calc` package and its `depthof` calculation :

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\abc}
\newlength{\nabc}
\setlength{\abc}{\depthof{glah}}
\setlength{\nabc}{-\abc}

\rule[\nabc]{0pt}{0pt}blah
\\[0.2\baselineskip]
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}

glah
\\[0.2\baselineskip]
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stole this answer from a different but related question, but I wanted to post here in case someone else came looking for it.  From: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51406/153289

```
{\normalfont\bfseries\libertine\scshape #1
    \par\strut\par
    \unskip\unskip\setbox0=\lastbox
    \vspace*{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\baselineskip\relax}}%
```

Where `#1` is a multiline argument, like: `Hello World\\This~is~a~test.` In my case, for an author who has Chapter titles that are two lines... (le sigh.)