# How to \smash all letters with descenders

Tags: spacing

Is there a way to systematically \smash the height of letters with descenders?

I got help normalizing the spacing after a line with descenders here:
[Preventing letters with descenders (g, q, y...) from affecting line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/421791/preventing-letters-with-descenders-g-q-y-from-affecting-line-spacing/421803#421803)
But descenders are messing up a bunch of other things as well. For instance, I need them to not affect the height of a box around an expression.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\fcolorbox{black}{blue}{\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
\hrule
\mybox{blah blah blah blah}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
\hrule
\mybox{blah blah blah glah}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

This gives different box heights depending on whether the last line has descenders, and I need it not to.

I want to find a way to systematically \smash all descenders, as it would prevent that type of issue from arising again in projects where I need vertical alignments to be consistent.

[image]

Edit: Alright, for this specific example with the boxes, I can simply add \vphantom{g}\vspace{-1pt} after the argument (given that the size of the descender is roughly 1pt). I'd still like to know if there's a more general way to get rid of the space taken by descenders.

Comment: The usual solution is to add a \strut anywhere in a box, or at the start and end of a \parbox or minipage.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yeah, I know, but as I said that gives some empty space between the last line and the bottom of the box, I'm trying to find a way to avoid that. I want to decrease the height of lines with descenders, not increase the height of lines without them.

Comment: `\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{...}` might work.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't think it does. I tried and the box doesn't fit the text if it's more than 1 line, and its height still depends on the presence of descenders. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses `\raisebox`.  The default baseline for a `\parbox` is the center.  To ignore the descenders in the last row, you need to use `\parbox[b]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\fcolorbox{black}{blue}{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{\parbox[b]{0.8\textwidth}{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
\hrule
\mybox{blah blah blah blah}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
\hrule
\mybox{blah blah blah glah}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Oh, I was missing the [b] option, thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 2):

Before applying the `\fcolorbox`, I truncate the depth of the bottom-aligned `\parbox` which I temporarily set in `\box0`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{%
  \fcolorbox{black}{blue}{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\parbox[b]{0.8\textwidth}{#1}}\dp0=0pt\relax\box0}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
\hrule
\mybox{blah blah blah blah}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
\hrule
\mybox{blah blah blah glah}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]