# How to get uniform vertical space space after section title

Tags: spacing, sectioning, vertical-alignment, minipage, mdframed

I have encountered a problem when working with `minipages`. Consider the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \section*{x}
    \begin{mdframed}
        Some text
    \end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \section*{y}
    \begin{mdframed}
        Some other text
    \end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The box on the right will start further down the page because the section title has a different height (depth?). I want to align the tops of the two boxes. Is there a simple way to do this using the tools I have chosen, or should I try a different approach?

Edit: Added screenshot of problem.
[image: Misaligned boxes]

Comment: [Preventing letters with descenders (g, q, y…) from affecting line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/421803/134144)  might be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a strut:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \section*{\strut x}
    \begin{mdframed}
        Some text
    \end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \section*{\strut y}
    \begin{mdframed}
        Some other text
    \end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works! I had tried using `\vphantom{y}`, but that does not seem to work in a section title (Edit: It works in the MWE, not in my original code. No idea why). I had not heard of `\strut`.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can add a `\protect\vphantom{y}` to have the same height. Note that anything inside sectioning commands must be robust or protected using `\protect`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \section*{x\protect\vphantom{y}}
    \begin{mdframed}
        Some text
    \end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \section*{y}
    \begin{mdframed}
        Some other text
    \end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I had tried this, but for some reason it will not compile in my original document, and I don't have time to figure out why. It works in the MWE though.

Comment: You need `\protect` for section to work, see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that works. Any advantage to using that over `\strut`?

Comment: `\strut` is deeper than `y`, whereas `\vphantom{y}` is exactly as deep as `y`.