# TikZ mdframed environment: close box at end of page and continue on next

Tags: page-breaking, boxes, mdframed, tikz-styles

I used the [Excursus environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50877/excursus-environment-using-mdframed-issue-with-page-breaks) as a template to create my own box like this:

```
\usepackage[style=1,leftmargin=0pt,rightmargin=0pt,framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newenvironment{boxtype1}{%

\begin{mdframed}%

[linewidth=.5,margin=8.5,backgroundcolor=gray!2,linecolor=red,fontcolor=black,roundcorner=10pt, middlelinewidth=2pt]%

\fontsize{12}{14}\sffamily\selectfont%
}{\end{mdframed}}
```

Works perfectly nice. However, would there be a way to automatically close the box at a page break and then open it new on the next one? If it would even be possible to have a "Excursus X continued" on each page that would be perfect.

Thanks

Philipp

Comment: Please provide a complete, compilable example. That is much more useful than a mere fragment of code and will encourage people to answer your question!

Comment: `everyline` [untested since no Minimum Working Example provided]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `everyline=true` option so that all parts of the `mdframed` get the whole frame. Using `middleextra` and `secondextra`, you can add material for the continuing parts of the `mdframed`. In the example below I added "Excursus (Cont.)" at the upper left part of the frame in the continuation parts.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{boxtype1}
  {%
  \begin{mdframed}[
    linewidth=.5,
    everyline=true,
    %margin=8.5,
    backgroundcolor=gray!2,
    linecolor=red,
    fontcolor=black,
    roundcorner=10pt,
    middlelinewidth=2pt,
    splittopskip=25pt,
    secondextra={
      \node[
        overlay,
        fill=white,
        anchor=west,
        font=\sffamily\large,
        inner xsep=10pt
      ] at ([xshift=10pt]O|-P) {Excursus (Cont.)};
      },
    middleextra={
      \node[
        overlay,
        fill=white,
        anchor=west,
        font=\sffamily\large,
        inner xsep=10pt
      ] at ([xshift=10pt]O|-P) {Excursus (Cont.)};
      }
  ]%
  \fontsize{12}{14}\sffamily\selectfont%
  }
  {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{boxtype1}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{boxtype1}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works! And looks awesome. Thanks. One question though, is there a way to control the bottom boundary of the box? The lower part of the letters touch the red line. Or is this my footer, which needs to be changed?

Comment: @user2334921 You're welcome! Regarding your question, you can control the separation between text and the bottom line using `innerbottommaring`, as in `innerbottommaring=40pt`. There's also `splitbottomskip` for the split components of the frame. If this doesn't solve your problem, I'll need to see some minimal, yet complete code illustrating the problem; otherwise, no effective advise can be provided.

Comment: Thanks again @GonzaloMedina. The `splitbottomskip` does the trick. Sorry for not providing an example. I will do this next time. Cheers  Philipp