# Design that imitate Google browser

Tags: diagrams, framed

I would like to write some tutorials about HTML, and I would like to do it efficiently without using too many screenshots.

What I would like to obtain is a frame which looks like a web browser, such as this.

[image: frame]

(Image from [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-browser).)

Comment: I suggest using TikZ and with some `nodes`. I’ll create an example this evening …

Comment: Thanks, there is no urgency and I think that will not be easy to do.

Comment: How about trying to put up an MWE?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? It seems a reasonable question to me.

Comment: @IanThompson my guess would be because the question looks a lot like “Please do it for me”.

Comment: Why not inserting the screenshot (as in the question) and add text in front of it?

Comment: @cgnieder --- Three downvotes is quite extreme for this site. Surely it's enough to ask the OP to post a code showing his/her efforts so far.

Comment: Please don't downvote below -1 for questions that aren't spam or abusive. If you feel that the question needs more work, leave a comment explaining this. Also, if you downvote, please don't forget to come back and revert your downvote once the question has been improved.

Comment: @IanThompson I completely agree

Comment: @projetmbc: “Thanks, there is no urgency and I think that will not be easy to do.” – Sure, it’s not easy, but this page is to be a help-your-self page. So one is contraint to do his homework and effort by himself. Otherwise: Pay for it ;-)

Comment: @Jake While I agree that in general it's better not to multiply downvote a question, many users can't know it has been downvoted unless it shows "-1".

Comment: @Tobi: Why such a comment ? If no one knows how to do that, that's not a problem. If you don't like my question, just pass to another question. Takes also a look here tex.stackexchange.com/users/6880/projetmbc?tab=answers to see that when I can I answer to questions. When I ask question without giving any MWE it is because I have no idea of how to do that. I really don't understand people who wastes time to acts like you've done. Just take a tea with one cheesecake when one question is not a good one. ;-)

Comment: I’m sorry maybe it was kind of overreaction – the emoticon should have shown that it was not too serious. But in general I (and others – I guess) think that this is a helping- and not a do-it-for-me-page. So it’s always nice to see what one tried before asking – even if it’s not possible to create an MWE, I’d like to read what on has tried so far, e.g. “I found some packages to make frames but none seems to allow this customization” …

Comment: As we say in french : "Sans racune".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{tab}{RGB}{223,223,223}
\definecolor{ugray}{RGB}{230,230,230}
\definecolor{bgray}{RGB}{151,151,151}
\definecolor{redball}{RGB}{238,93,86}
\definecolor{yellowball}{RGB}{254,184,75}
\definecolor{greenball}{RGB}{152,204,122}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,
  minimum width=0.8\textwidth,
  minimum height=8cm,
  rounded corners=2pt
]  (rect) {};
\shade[draw,
  rounded corners=2pt,
  top color=ugray,
  bottom color=bgray
] (rect.north west) -- 
  (rect.north east) --
  ( $ (rect.north east) + (0,-1.3) $ ) --
  ( $ (rect.north west) + (0,-1.3) $ ) --
  cycle;
\draw[rounded corners=1pt,fill=tab] 
  (rect.149) --  
  ++(2,0) --  
  coordinate (a) ++(0.3,0.7) -- 
  ++(4,0) --  
  coordinate (b) ++(0.3,-0.7) --
  (rect.31) --
  ++(0,-1) --
  ++(\the\dimexpr-0.8\textwidth-\pgflinewidth\relax,0) --
  cycle;
\node[draw=gray,
  rounded corners=1pt,
  fill=white,
  minimum width=0.7\textwidth,
  minimum height=16pt,yshift=68.5pt
] (write) {};
\shadedraw[draw=gray,shading=ball,ball color=redball] 
  ([xshift=15pt,yshift=-17pt]rect.north west) circle (4.5pt);
\shadedraw[draw=gray,shading=ball,ball color=yellowball] 
  ([xshift=30pt,yshift=-17pt]rect.north west) circle (4.5pt);
\shadedraw[draw=gray,shading=ball,ball color=greenball] 
  ([xshift=45pt,yshift=-17pt]rect.north west) circle (4.5pt);
\draw[gray,ultra thick]
  ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=-4pt]b) -- 
  ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=1pt]b);
\draw[gray,ultra thick]
  ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=1pt]b) -- 
  ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=-4pt]b);
\node[xshift=11pt,yshift=-1pt] at (a) 
  {\includegraphics[width=10pt]{globe}};
\node[xshift=11pt] at (write.west) 
  {\includegraphics[width=10pt]{globe}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The [`globe image`](http://findicons.com/icon/24484/globe?id=358228) used was taken from [`findicons.com`](http://findicons.com/).

Comment: This question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47537/access-mdframed-node-coordinates-with-tikz)  shows how one could turn this into a frame using `mdframed` …

Comment: Probably a command that allows for the title of the webpage, url and possible frame like a minipage to able to fill the space of the browser would be good as well? Just saying :)

Comment: The hardest has been done. Great !